# How to append DOM Element into an empty element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, appendchild

I have bunch of objects that return a DOM-tree that I then use to append to an element. For example,

```
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
```

and I will eventually end up in something like:

```
<div>
<div id="...">...</div>
<div id="...">...</div>
<div id="...">...</div>
</div>
```

Those three DIVs were created by third party code, and I am wrapping them around my DIV tag here, but what I want instead is to just append them to an empty element, but it doesn't work:

```
var elem = document.createElement('');
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
elem.appendChild(callSomePrototypesMethod());
```

Expected results:

```
<div id="...">...</div>
<div id="...">...</div>
<div id="...">...</div>
```

I'm not sure if this makes any sense to you, but I need to use DOM, and I can't put those content within any other elements...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That's what [document fragments](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/DocumentFragment) are for. You can create a new fragment via [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.createDocumentFragment) and use it as if it were a single element.

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to read the OP's mind and determine that he wanted to carry a NodeList around, but, as written, the question seemed to ask about an element in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you want insert the specifieds elements directly in the body of document (not inside an other element like a 'div'), try

`document.body.appendChild( callSomePrototypesMethod() );`

There is a note about 'document.body.appendChild' in IE. See http://danielsaidi.wordpress.com/tag/documentbodyappendchild/.